# How to aggregate evaluation metrics from many evaluations?

Tags: meta-analysis, text-mining, natural-language, precision-recall, aggregation

Say I'm developing an automatic term extractor and I have a lot of documents. Let's assume this documents do not all have the same size. I also have a list of terms that should be extracted from each document, the gold standards.

When I apply the term extractor to each of the documents I get a list of terms and I can calculate, for example, the precision score of the extractor for each document. For example:

**Document 1**

- Gold -> ('head', 'nail', 'toe')
- Extracted -> ('head', 'cereal')
- Precision = 0.5

**Document 2**

- Gold -> ('belly', 'limb', 'migraine', 'colon')
- Extracted -> ('limb', 'tea', 'John', 'red')
- Precision = 0.25

Ok, now I have a precision score of my term extractor for each document, so I have a lot of precision scores. How can I aggregate them into just one precision score which can be used to evaluate the system, in the case that:

1. I only have this precision values?
2. I have the raw data?

Comment: You mean that you get 1 precision for each document? Are all the documents the same size? Do you have all the raw data, or only the list of precisions?

Comment: Edited post, adding answers to the questions of the commenter above.

Comment: If precisions are proportions then you can perform a meta-analysis using any of the standard methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the task as [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification), and use the typical metrics for multi-label classification, e.g. excerpt from {2}:

[image]

Wikipedia also has a section on [Statistics and evaluation metrics for Multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Multi-label_classification&oldid=752508281#Statistics_and_evaluation_metrics).

But keep in mind that term extraction is a bit different, as explained in {1}:

> Despite these first evaluation experiences, no comprehensive
>   and global framework has yet been proposed
>   for computational terminology as there exist for many
>   other NLP fields. Beside economic factors, it seems
>   that evaluating terminology acquisition raises some
>   specific intrinsic difficulties.
>
> [...]
>
> As mentioned above, traditional metrics of precision
>   and recall are not appropriate for term extraction evaluation.
>   One problem is that term relevance is a gradual
>   rather than a binary notion and that one cannot
>   expect all extractors or terminologists to deliver
>   ranked list of terms. This led us to stem relevance on
>   a terminological distance. A second problem is that
>   no terminological standard can be considered as a stable
>   and unique gold standard.

FYI [Getting the accuracy for multi-label prediction in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239577/395857)

---

References:

- {1} Nazarenko, Adeline, and Haifa Zargayouna. "Evaluating term extraction." In International Conference Recent Advances in Natural Language Processing (RANLP'09), pp. 299-304. 2009. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10075060291670172889&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://anthology.aclweb.org/R/R09/R09-1.pdf#page=323 ; https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a953/001b2be9b73574418ba42f8f48017629e11e.pdf
- {2} Tsoumakas, Grigorios, and Ioannis Katakis. "[Multi-label classification: An overview.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6287724239179279830&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)" Dept. of Informatics, Aristotle University of Thessaloniki, Greece (2006).